# How can I only catch the 'Directory not empty' error

Tags: python

I'm writing a bash-like Windows command prompt in python for fun and I need to catch the 'Directory not empty' error to prevent my program from crashing. How can I do this?

```
import os, sys

# Take the user input
user_input = input()

# Split the user input
parts = user_input.split()

# Remove a directory
if "rmdir" == parts[0]:
    os.rmdir(os.getcwd() + "\\" + parts[1])
```

Comment: Are you familiar with *try / except* ?

Comment: Yes, but I need to give an output only for the directory not empty error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle the "Directory not empty" exception in some special way then:

```
import os
try:
    os.rmdir('your_directory_goes_here')
except OSError as e:
    if e.strerror == 'Directory not empty':
        print('No can do')
    else:
        raise e
```